# RememberMe Service not working

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller

I am using RememberMe service in Spring MVC. It used to be working but now it's not. It create a Cookie but when Restart the browser, the cookie will remove automatically. I tested with 3-4 machines, it's not a browser issue. It may be some configuration issue. We use Token based rememberMe service with the following configuration in Spring Security.

```
<bean id="shoTokenBasedRememberMeServices" class="com.sho.web.security.ShoTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg ref="shoUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
<constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
<constructor-arg ref="shoTokenBasedRememberMeServices"/>
</bean>

Answer (score 0):

I went through this particular issue. I solved it by adding a RememberMeAuthenticationProvider to my authentication manager.

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        ...
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authMgr">
        ...
        <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

So my authentication manager ended up with two authentication providers:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authMgr">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha">
                <salt-source user-property="username" />
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

This article says "Include the RememberMeAuthenticationProvider in your AuthenticationManager": http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html